# SQL "AS" statement with "*"

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a search form using multiple tables.

My problem lies in the " name AS name, * " part, where it wont use the name as name and find everyting in the table at the same time.

This is my SQL query:

```
    SELECT name AS name, * FROM files_plus WHERE name LIKE '%$query%' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT username AS name FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$query%' 
    LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Also no sql standard allows the use of `*` after explicit columns in the select expression

Comment: Even if i type the cloumn name, it wont work since i'm using the AS statement.

Comment: Try qualifying with the table names: `files_plus.name, files_plus.*` since that syntax is allowed for joins (`select t1.*, t2.col from t1 join t2`)

Comment: The use of `*` of will vary a little bit between platforms. You didn't specify which flavor of SQL you're doing.

Comment: I need more information from the first table than the other table, but it wont let med select anything else form the first table... even if i erase "name AS name" and use * instead, won't work.

Comment: You can't `union` two tables together if the columns are compatible with each other. You must also return the same number of columns in each half of the union. This will give you a "vertical" union. If you want something more like a "horizonal union" then look into joins.

Comment: Is ther any way to make a work-around?

Comment: There's probably a simple solution. You haven't really explained what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to union the names first, then do a `LEFT JOIN` to get the other columns from `files_plus`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT name AS name FROM files_plus WHERE name LIKE '%$query%' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT username AS name FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$query%' )
 AS names
LEFT JOIN files_plus ON names.name = files_plus.name
```

You'll have a duplicate column for `name`, but you would have had that in your original query.

Comment: That somewhat works, except it doesnt show names from the second table (users).

Comment: Do you have overlap between the names? If so you'll need an additional column to identify the source.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT name AS name" is the same as "SELECT name FROM....". Secondly, "SELECT name..." is a part of "SELECT * FROM...". Write something like "SELECT * FROM..." and you'll have no trouble retrieving your information